# Wrong Htaccess Redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im using this htaccess code..

```html
RewriteRule ^city/barcelona ?what=2&type=barcelona
RewriteRule ^city/newyork ?what=2&type=newyork
RewriteRule ^city/paris ?what=2&type=paris
RewriteRule ^city/london ?what=2&type=london
RewriteRule ^city/milan ?what=2&type=milan

RewriteRule ^city ?what=3 [L]
```

But, when i open **www.example.com/city/tokyo**, it opens **www.example.com/city**  (there is no tokyo option.. it must return 404 page)

How can correct my htaccess code?

(for example.. can i say something like that: if city is newyork, paris or london, do this rewrite rule.. else = 404)

Comment: @anubhava its ok.. milan page is open (?what=2&type=milan).

Comment: Then what URL is not working and what is the error?

Comment: i correct the question.. for example, if i open www.example.com/city/tokyo, the browser opens www.example.com/city (it must return 404).. there is no tokyo option..

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^city$ ?what=3 [L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^city ?what=3 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening due to anchors not being used in your rules. Hence your last rule is always matching any URI starting with `/city.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^city/barcelona/?$ ?what=2&type=barcelona [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^city/newyork/?$ ?what=2&type=newyork [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^city/paris/?$ ?what=2&type=paris [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^city/london/?$ ?what=2&type=london [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^city/milan/?$ ?what=2&type=milan [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^city/?$ ?what=3 [L,QSA]
```